# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setVisible' of undefined , filtering using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, filtering

I want to filter the array based on search result. I came up with this code but it shows error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setVisible' of undefined`

```
var viewmodel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.location = ko.observableArray(locations) 
    self.query = ko.observable('');
    //filtering
    self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
        var query = self.query().toLowerCase(); // to convert to lowercase

        if(!query) {
            for(var i = 0; i < self.location.length; i++) {
                self.location()[i].marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            return self.location();
        }
        else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(locations, function(item) {
                var match = item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(query)!==-1;
                item.marker.setVisible(match); //display the filtered markers ,**error is shown in this line**
                return match;
            })
        }
    }, self)
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

Comment: There's no `marker` value in your `locations` so it can't access a `setVisible` function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error indicates that it's trying to read a property (`setVisible`) of an undefined reference. You can track this down by down a simple search for `setVisible` and checking where the issue may be: either the `marker` in your `for` loop is undefined or the one in the `else` block is. You have 2 mistakes that could be causing your problem in either location:

1. `for(var i = 0; i < self.location.length; i++) {`: You need to check against `self.location().length` otherwise you're asking for the length property of the observable, not the array.
2. `ko.utils.arrayFilter(locations, function(item) {`: You need to pass in `self.locations()` otherwise you're not actually giving the function an array.

Both issues seem to be mistakes with using the observable vs. the underlying data. You must call an observable like a function in order to read the underlying data. The exception to this is knockout defined functions such as `splice` or `removeAll()` that are meant to be used on observables.